# Constantly checking to see if secondary hard drive failed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, hard-drive

I would like to constantly (every 30 seconds) check and see if secondary(sdb) hard drive failed. What would be the most optimal way of doing so. Should I check by simply seeing if /dev/sdb exists, or is there a better method?
Also I would like to check from secondary hard drive if primary failed, and if so I would like to execute a reboot command.

Currently I am thinking of doing

For checking if secondary hard drive failed I constantly execute this in while loop

```
if [ -e /dev/sda ];
then
    echo "Secondary Hard drive is connected"
    sleep 30s
else
    echo "Secondary Hard drive died"
fi
```

To check if primary hard drive failed I constantly execute this in while loop

```
if [ -e /dev/sda ];
then
    echo "Hard drive is connected"
    sleep 30s
else
    echo "Hard drive died"
    reboot
fi
```

I am not sure how to imitate hard drive failure, but I would like input and or suggestions about how to do this, and whether the code will work.
Thanks to anyone in advance for their help :)

Comment: Just curious: What do you use your secondary hard drive for?

Comment: A cron job would be more efficient than running code in a loop, no?

Comment: You might want to consider this: Hard drive failure might not always correspond to the device file vanishing from `/dev`

Comment: @ArjunShankar I am just going to be writing massive amounts of data to the hard drive at very high frequency, and would like to see when failure happens, and when it does happen I would like to be notified of it. The hard drive is sdd and has a very small amount of space (10MB). Just a fun project I am attempting, and would like to find a way to detect hard drive failure when it does happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that /dev/sd_'s existence is not tied clearly to drive functionality. I think that drive could catch fire and you might still have a /dev node.

Instead, try to look at [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.), and specifically, with [something like smartd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/?_test=b) if your hardware supports it.

Comment: +1. This is the right way to do it, if the HDD is SMART capable. Also: http://linux.die.net/man/8/smartd

Comment: I have just tried this out. And it is exactly what was needed. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Think about using a RAID1 (md) - in this case the system does the check and all the housekeeping automatically.

Note: It might not be a good idea to directly reboot if a harddrive crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This S.M.A.R.T link that digitalRoss posted seems to clear the problem http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/?_test=b [hard drive](http://www.harddrivesforsale.com/) try checking if statement if /dev/sdb exists